# AppCenter react native ios build fails "usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 "

Tags: ios, react-native, build, visual-studio-app-center

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

when i try build react-native IOS on the Appcenter The error appears in these 2 files **main.jsbundle and assets.** Works fine on local computer (emulator and physical device)

```
The following build commands failed:

CpResource /Users/runner/runners/2.169.1/work/1/s/ios/main.jsbundle /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[APPNAME]-adrecrevrfgahhfyzlogcbrpednj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/[APPNAME]/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/DGFonder.app/main.jsbundle CpResource /Users/runner/runners/2.169.1/work/1/s/ios/assets /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[APPNAME]-adrecrevrfgahhfyzlogcbrpednj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DGFonder/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/[APPNAME].app/assets (2 failures)

[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 [section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed) [section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
```

When i try enable to "Legacy Build System" I no longer receive this error. But I get another error like

```
**ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient**

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DGFonder-adrecrevrfgahhfyzlogcbrpednj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DGFonder/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/BVLinearGradient'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
```

System:

```
Platforms: iOS 13.4, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2


OS: macOS 10.15.3
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 59.17 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.9.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.4, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
Xcode: 11.4.1/11E503a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 1.8.0_242 - /usr/bin/javac
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1
react-native: ^0.62.2 => 0.62.2
npmGlobalPackages:

 pod --version. 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first make sure if you really have BVLinearGradient in your project, no matter source code or library.

Comment: Hi Neal. I am using BVLinearGradient in my project.

Comment: @IbrahimYolbir So first check if the native part of that lib is properly installed. If not, reinstall it. I’ve encountered problem like yours before.

Comment: I tried to reinstall many times. And tried also linking manual and automatically

Comment: @IbrahimYolbir So, as the linker error shows, It can not find the lib  in the building directory. You may check out what happened there.